# Proof, is $\forall x : (P(x) \lor Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x : P(x) \lor \forall x : Q(x)$?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have to prove if the following statement is true or false
$$\forall x : (P(x) \lor Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x : P(x) \lor \forall x : Q(x)$$

I understand the first statement as, for every $x$, at least one of the functions $P$, $Q$ is true. For the second statement, at least one of the functions $P$, $Q$ is true for every $x$. Is this correct? When yes, how could I prove this? Using the distributive law will clearly render me the wrong result.

Comment: I would suggest trying out some examples to see how this works.

Comment: @Sasha, really?

Comment: Read again what you wrote here - there is the answer to your question. If you understand what is going on, creating a counterexample will be a piece of cake.

Comment: Let $P(x)$ be $x$ is even and let $Q(x)$ be $x$ is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *think* your understanding is right, except that "at least one of the functions $P$, $Q$ is true for every $x$" is somewhat ambiguous in ordinary English. It could mean either the left-hand side of your goal or the right-hand side of your goal.

Before you start figuring out how to prove the statement, you should give some thought to whether you would *expect* it to be true at all. If it's not true, searching for a proof will be futile. Is there some easy counterexample to find, perhaps?

For example, for every natural number it is true that it is even *or* that it is odd. What does your formula claim when applied to that fact?

Comment: @AMPerrine Guys, I think I found my problem. The problem is the way I read it. When I see $\forall x : P(x)$, I think, P(x) is true for every x, which means, this always returns true. $\forall x : Q(x)$, Q(X) is true for every x, this means this always returns true. Until here everything is perfectly fine. Here comes my mistake: I then think, so, I guess true $\lor$ true, is always true, right? Wrong!

Comment: Another question, $\forall x : P(x) \lor \forall x : Q(x)$, is this the same x for both equations?

Comment: true $\lor$ true is always true. I think your problem is that you're somehow ignoring the quantifiers. Can you repeat your argument with all of the "this"es unfolded? I think something might be buried there.

Comment: $\forall x : P(x) \lor \forall x : Q(x)$ is the same as $\forall s : P(x) \lor \forall t : Q(t)$ is the same as $\forall b : P(b) \lor \forall w : Q(w)$. The scope of each variable bound by $\forall$ is only the formula immediately after it.

Comment: I don't really get it then... $\forall x : P(x)$ means, P(x) is true for every x and $\forall y : Q(y)$ also means, Q(y) is true for every y. Then the whole thing has to be always true. If I pick P(x) as "x is even" and Q(y) as "y is odd", then it isn't a valid example for the integer numbers set, because P(x) is not true for every x. Where did I go wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If you pick $P(x)$ as "$x$ is even", then certainly it is not the case that $\forall x\,P(x)$ is false, and $\forall y\,P(y)$ is also false, but how does that make you think the example isn't "valid"? It just means that $\forall x\,P(x)\lor \forall x\,Q(x)$ evaluates to false. So what about that? It's a perfectly good truth value, and we can compare it to the truth value $\forall x\,(P(x)\lor Q(x))$ evaluates to, to see whether they are the same. If they aren't, then the entire $\Leftrightarrow$ will evaluate to false ...

Comment: [OOPS! The "certainly it is not" above should not have the "not". Please pretend it isn't there!] ... and to prove $\text{blah}\Leftrightarrow\text{blah}$ means to convince ourselves and the reader that _no matter how we pick $P$ and $Q$_, the $\Leftrightarrow$ will evaluate to true. Finding even one $P$ and $Q$ where it evaluates to false means that we have a _counterexample_, i.e. what we're being asked to prove does not actually hold. Thus, there'd better not be any proof of it, and it would be foolish to try to find one.

Comment: oh, I guess I had misunderstood then! I thought that when you wrote $\forall x\,P(x)$, it just couldn't be false. I thought it was a statement, saying, you have to pick a P(x) that always returns true for a given set. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

$\forall x \in \{0,1\}$ either $x = 0$ or $x = 1$
but it isn't true that $\forall x \in \{0,1\}$, $ x = 0 \ $  or $\forall x \in \{0,1\}$, $ x = 1$.

Comment: And rewriting $\{0,1\}$ as $\{0 \mod 2, 1 \mod 2\}$, we have another "solution"!